# Unable to find a specification for `PayPalHereSDKv2`

Tags: xcode, paypal, cocoapods, paypal-sandbox, paypal-here

This is the code needed to be run : `pod try PayPalHereSDKv2`

and this is the error I get:

```
pod try PayPalHereSDKv2
Setup completed
Updating spec repositories
[!] Unable to find a specification for PayPalHereSDKv2
```

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-here-sdk-ios-distribution

https://cocoapods.org/pods/PayPalHereSDKv2

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/using-sample-apps/#work-with-the-sample-apps

how do I get rid of the error?